# document.getElementById().click(); dont works on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, mobile

I'm trying to run this, on desktop it works fine but it doesn't work on mobile devices

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px">
   <p style="text-align: center; color: white; margin-bottom: 10px">Experimente o Wi-Fi gratuitamente! Curta e compartilhe nossa página!</p>
   <a id="freebot" class="button" onclick="sharePost();" href="#">Entre com o Facebook</a>
   <a id="loginfree" href="$(link-login-only)?dst=$(link-orig-esc)&amp;username=T-$(mac-esc)"></a>
</div>
```

This is the function I want to perform

```
function authHotspotMikrotik() {
    document.getElementById("loginfree").click();
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: This JavaScript would work on any browser. What exactly is going wrong? It's unclear.

Comment: @ADyson, when on desktop, the function runs perfectly by opening the link (href), but it does not run on mobile

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to simulate a mouse click, you need to create a mouse event and dispatch it.

```js
let simulateClick = function(elem) {
  // Create our event (with options)
  let evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });
  // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
  let canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};


simulateClick(document.getElementById("loginfree"))
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 30px">
  <p style="text-align: center; color: white; margin-bottom: 10px">Experimente o Wi-Fi gratuitamente! Curta e compartilhe nossa página!</p>
  <a id="freebot" class="button" onclick="sharePost();" href="#">Entre com o Facebook</a>
  <a id="loginfree" href='https://google.com'>click element</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but it still doesn't work on mobile, on desktops it works perfectly. Wouldn't there be a way for me to call this "href id=loginfree" directly inside javascript without the need to simulate a click or create the element in html?

Comment: your URL looks weird. can you tell me how that resolves? `$(link-login-only)?dst=$(link-orig-esc)&amp;username=T-$(mac-esc)` how is that getting interpretted into an actual URL?

Comment: to make it a little more simplified I could use this link: https://example.com/login?username=T-$(mac-esc), the variable $(mac-esc) would be replaced by the mac of the device that is logging in and sent to the mikrotik router

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with the fact that the desktop opens a popup and mobile devices open a NEW TAB, sorry if I said something nonsense it's because I'm starting now

Comment: You know, I'm not sure exactly what the question is any more. Is it that you can't open a popup? Or can't trigger a click programatically? or... ?

Comment: sorry i posted an answer with my current code and my doubt

Answer (score 0):

I these code modifications:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Amazon Inter.Net Wi-Fi - Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- two other colors

<body class="lite">
<body class="dark">

-->

    $(if chap-id)
    <form name="sendin" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post" style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password" />
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="$(link-orig)" />
        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
    </form>

    <script src="/md5.js"></script>
    <script>
        function doLogin() {
            document.sendin.username.value = document.login.username.value;
            document.sendin.password.value = hexMD5('$(chap-id)' + document.login.password.value + '$(chap-challenge)');
            document.sendin.submit();
            return false;
        }

    </script>
    $(endif)


    <div class="ie-fixMinHeight">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="wrap animated fadeIn">
                <form name="login" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post" $(if chap-id) onSubmit="return doLogin()" $(endif)>
                    <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="$(link-orig)" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="#">


                    <p class="info $(if error)alert$(endif)">
                        $(if error == "")Digite seu e-mail e senha para utilizar o Wi-Fi da Amazon Inter.net$(endif)

                        $(if error)$(error)$(endif)
                    </p>
                    <label>
                        <img class="ico" src="img/user.svg" alt="#" />
                        <input name="username" type="text" value="$(username)" placeholder="E-mail" />
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <img class="ico" src="img/password.svg" alt="#" />
                        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
                    </label>

                    <p style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                        <a style="color: white" href="#">Esqueci minha senha?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Conectar" />
                        <a id="cadbot" class="button" href="#">Cadastre-se</a>
                    </p>

    $(if trial == 'yes')
        <script async defer src="js/sdk.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'           // id do app criado no facebook
            
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId            : app_id,
                autoLogAppEvents : true,
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v3.3'
            });
        };

        function sharePost(){
            FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'share',
                    href: 'https://www.facebook.com/amazoninter.net.br',
                },

                // callback
                function(response) {
                    if (response && !response.error_message) {
                        window.open('https://example.com/login?username=T-$(mac-esc)', '_self');
                    } else {
                        alert('Erro durante a postagem.');
                    }
                }
                );
            }
        </script>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px">
            <p style="text-align: center; color: white; margin-bottom: 10px">Experimente o Wi-Fi gratuitamente! Curta e compartilhe nossa página!</p>
            <a id="freebot" class="button" onclick="sharePost();" href="#">Entre com o Facebook</a>
        </div>
    $(endif)
</form>
<p class="info bt">Desenvolvido por Departamento de TI - Amazon Inter.Net</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you look at the sharePost(); function, I open the link in the facebook callback, on the desktop it opens the link normally and replaces the php variable "$(mac-esc) with the MAC address of the device that shared the post and login is done, but on mobile devices after the post is done it apparently does not open the link and does not replace the variable "$(mac-esc)" with the MAC of the smartphone, it simply closes the TAB opened by the smartphone and goes back to the login screen. Then my question comes in, is the fact that the desktop opens a POPUP and the mobile device opens a NEW TAB could be the cause of the problem?